# Question about assimilation

Tags: phonetics, consonants

*Good day* [ɡʊ**d d**eɪ]  and *at time* [ə**t t**aɪm] - is it a **partial assimilation**(loss of plossion), or maybe **complete assimilation** like in *horse-shoe?*

And what about **don’t you** ? I know there's a form **doncha [ˈdoʊntʃə]** - is it a reduction? Or some other process?

Comment: Transitioning rapidly from the final dental [t] of "don't" to the initial palatal of "you" produces a sound like the "ch" in "church" because the breath for the vowel in "you" is beginning to be let out while the tongue is still pressed against the roof of the mouth (alveolo-palatally).  The spelling "doncha" (so-called 'eye-dialect' ) is an attempt to reflect this informal-conversational pronunciation.

Comment: It's called yod coalescence.

Comment: Thanks,and what about assimilation?

Answer (score 1):

The assimilation of *good day* transforms [ɡʊd deɪ] to [ɡʊ deɪ]. This is complete assimilation as the assimilated phoneme and assimilating phoneme fully coincide. The same can be said of *at time* which transforms [ət taɪm] to [ə taɪm].

Your third example of *don't you* is an intermediate assimilation. Many native English speakers assimilate it by altering it to [dəʊn'ju]. On the other hand, your example *"doncha"* is, as TRomano states, an attempt to reflect informal-conversational pronunciation.

Comment: *The same can be said of at time which transforms [ət taɪm] to [ə taɪm]* --- That's incorrect. Try pronouncing *at time* with a single t, it becomes 'atime' which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> Good day [ɡʊd deɪ] and at time [ət taɪm] - is it a partial assimilation(loss of plossion), or maybe complete assimilation like in horse-shoe?

In 'good day', you can call it 'complete assimilation' but there's a specific name for this.

This is called **gemination/ consonant twinning** or **consonant lengthening**.

In 'good day', the d geminates/ lengthens because 'good' ends with d and 'day' starts with d. In 'at time', the t geminates.

**[Gemination - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination)**

I disagree with [omnidisciplinarianist's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/81968/106592):

> The assimilation of good day transforms [ɡʊd deɪ] to [ɡʊ deɪ].
>
> The same can be said of at time which transforms [ət taɪm] to [ə taɪm].

This is not true at all.

[ɡʊd deɪ] does not transform to [ɡʊ deɪ], rather, it transforms to [ɡʊddeɪ], the d geminates/lenghthens.

Likewise, *at time* [ət] [taɪm] does not transform to [ə taɪm] (try it yourself - try saying *at time* with a single t, it will become 'atime' which is incorrect.)